# getXmlHolder and context.expand - What does the arguments description mean

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to insert values into the Request and Capture the response from the soapui pro Testsuite/testcase/testStep, using groovy script, without creating any property or assertions using soapui pro wizard. Everything i am trying to do using groovy script file in Soapui pro. But after 11 days of my self learning process I am forced to ask the in the forum:

I went thru almost 100 sites talking about how to capture request/response value. 
But none explains the following:

1. ***getXmlHolder*** ("DeliverStatus#Request") 
   what does "deliveryStatus" & "Request" means and what does it contains. Which part of xml file is it. What does it signify
2. ***context.expand***

For all my attempts i have got Null exception.
But i have been able to successfull script using groovy in the "Script tab in the Response section". But unable to do in using testsuite Groovy Script.

Please help.. Thanking all in advance

Regards

Am

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DeliverStatus` is basically meaningless - it is the name of **your** test step.

`Request` means that you look at the XML request that will be sent by `SoapUI`.

You can replace `Request` with `Response` and get the result of the API call.

`context.expend` allows you to get the value of the request or the response as well as specific `XPath`s within them. I'm not familiar with the `getXmlHolder` method - but it looks like it gets an XML string as input (can be a fragment) and turns it into an object you can work with.

My recommendation - if you are not using it already, is to right click on the `Groovy` editing area and choose `Get Data` --> `Test Suite` --> `Test Case` --> `Test Step` --> `Response` -->  and navigate to the path in the response to which you want to access.
This will set the value of that XML fragment into a string variable of your choosing.

Afterwards you can use the `getXmlHolder` to convert that string into an object.
I also recommend using the [XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) for parsing an XML string into an object.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the reply. I am still not able to insert data into request wihout using soapui functions.

Comment: @amit - can you try and clarify exactly what you need - I'm not sure I understood what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I was trying to call any testcase from any testsuite. I have been able to successfully able to complete it. Just on the basis of your reply. **Thanks a lot @Ronk**

Comment: Happy to hear that :)
Feel free to mark the answer has helpfull :)

Comment: Although the Answer is already some kind of old, it saved the Day to me, for which i want to thank you.

Beforehand i tried to extract the Data in one Testcase, put it into a temporary Variable in order to read from it from another Testcase.
With your Solution this runs very smooth now.

Comment: Sure thing @Kaot - I'm happy it helped you :)